# Representing relationships between members of an EE site?

Tags: members, relationships, ee3

Curious to know if there is a good / best way to capture relationships between members of an EE site - for example parents / children where both could be members of the same site?

I can see it would be possible to do this via a channel entry system - where you create a channel entry for each member and then use stock relationship fields to capture inter-member relationships, but this requires effectively duplicating the EE member data in a field - with lots of scope for messing things up (and involves considerable redundancy of effort).

But since you cannot add a relationship type field to a member in EE - so at the moment this seems the only way.

Thanks in advance for whatever thoughts / guidance is available.

For record - this is for a new build EE3 site (currently on 3.4.6).

Answer (score 1):

Gavin,

I would recommend that you use [Zoo Visitor](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor) to accomplish. Once installed it will convert your existing members to entries in a channel where you can easily add a relationship or any other field type that you want to use.

I've used Zoo Visitor a few times and it's dead easy to use.

woops just noticed that it's only available for EE2. Assuming you're using EE3 look at [Solspace User](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/user). Haven't used it but pretty sure it will allow you to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I've had a good look at the Solspace User add-on, and so far not seen anything there that adds relationships between users as a thing - even there are many nice things, including the ability to relate  users to a channel entry posting, it is the linking of one user to another that I'm trying to do: I guess I may have to cook up some long hand solution to this one.